# Concatenate elements in list by order in Python

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I'm doing web scraping for prices, and in this particular site, they have the main prices in one class, and the cents in another class.

[image]

Basically I'm attributing each class to a list, so I'll end up with something looking like this:

```
prices = ["69", "99", "109"]
decimals = [",90", ",99", ",89"]
```

What I need is the resulting list:

```
full_price = ["69,90", "99,99", "109,89"]
```

I tried using two loops and append, but ended up having multiple undesired combinations.
[image]

How to I achieve the full_price list desired?

Comment: you only need one loop, since you want a one to one correspondence, not all combinations. Just do `list3 = [prices[i] + decimals[i] for i in range(len(prices))]`  or use `zip` as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it rather easily by using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
prices = ["69", "99", "109"]
decimals = [",90", ",99", ",89"]
full_price = [''.join(x) for x in zip(prices, decimals)]
```